# Prove that any set of integers that are relatively prime in pairs are relatively prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It seems pretty obvious, but how to prove?

I thought that maybe the way to go was by contradiction.  So suppose that a set of integers is not relatively prime but pairs of members are coprime.  We know for the set 
$$S=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_{n-1},a_n\}$$
$(a_i,a_j)=1,  \forall i,j, i\neq j$  If the set of integers was not coprime, then 
$$(a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_{n-1},a_n)=k$$
for some integer $k$.  By the definition of the greatest common divisor, we know that $$k|a_i, \forall a_i\in S$$
However, for all pairs $a_i, a_j$, the only number that divides each is $1$ since $(a_i,a_j)=1$  Thus, no members of $S$ have a common divisor of $k$ which is a contradition.  Therefore, the set of integers that are relatively prime in pairs is also relatively prime

Is this logical?  I know there is a theorem that states $(a_1,a_2,...a_{n-1},a_n)=((a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-1}),a_n)$ which might help the cause, but that exercise has not been crossed yet in my textbook, and I think that the linear fashion of the text should be upheld...  Thoughts?

Comment: At this level of elementary-hood I would expect to see "$\ldots$" replaced by induction. Otherwise it's good. But there's not need to assume they are not co-prime. Just take $k$ as you did and conclude  $k=1$.

Comment: Your proof is correct. Another way to see this, is to note that in the principal ideal domain $\Bbb Z$ the ideal $(a,b)$ is generated by the $gcd(a,b)$. So if $(a,b) = \Bbb Z$, i.e. $gcd(a,b) = 1$, then $(a,b,c) = \Bbb Z$ for every $c \in \Bbb Z$. So in fact, we only need $(a,b) = 1$ for two elements in $S$ rather then for every pair $(a,b)$.

Comment: What if $n=1$ and $a_1\gt1$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty much as you have said.  To put it more concisely, . . .

Let $d$ be a positive common factor of $a_1,\ldots,a_n$.  Then $d$ is a common factor of $a_1,a_2$.  Since by assumption the numbers are relatively prime in pairs, $d$ can only be $1$.

Comment: So i was right there...I just needed $a_1$ and $a_2$.  Awesome!

Comment: The assumption "$n\ge2$" was not stated in the question.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $ $ For sets of naturals, the property  of having a nontrivial common divisor *descends* to subsets, therefore, the negation of the property, having no nontrivial common divisor, *ascends* to supersets.